# ¿Cuál es la condición para que un árbol binario esté balanceado?

Tags: java, árboles-binarios

estoy entrado al mundo de los árboles mediante Java, y me surgió esta duda: ¿Que proceso o la teoría que debo de seguir para conocer si un árbol binario está balanceado?

Muchas Gracias por su tiempo.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que leas sobre [AVL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rbol_AVL)

El lenguaje es indiferente a las estructuras o algoritmos, pero puedes hacer una función "altura" recursiva que retorne 0 si el arbol es NULL, y MAX(altura(tree1),altura(tree2)) + 1 en otro caso para calcular la altura del arbol.

Ademas, podes agregar que si ABS(altura(tree1) - altura(tree2)) > 1 lance un error.

Es decir, si tengo un subArbol que contiene a sus hijos con una diferencia de altura mayor a 1, entonces ese subArbol no esta balanceado

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tu tiempo :), solo una ultima duda, ¿si un subArbol está desbalanceado, entonces el árbol que lo contiene está desbalanceado de igual forma?

Comment: Asi es. Es una condicion que se debe cumplir a lo largo de todo el arbol